# What is the fastest way to see if a node has a child with a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if a node has a certain tag in itself or one of it's children in JavaScript.

```
<html>
     <body>
         <p>
             <h3><a> This link lead nowhere!</a> </h3>
         </p>
     </body>
</html>
```

For example, in the above code, if I was given the node which is responsible for the p tag, and want to check if it has a link in it, what would be the fastest way to just check that (without having the actual node for the link)?

If the given node's name was "node", would it be faster to do:

```
function nodeContainsTag(node) {
    return node.tagName == "A" || node.getElementsByTagName("a").length > 0 ;
}
```

or

```
function nodeContainsTag(node) {
    return node.outerHTML.indexOf("<a") > 0;
}
```

Is the second function even guaranteed to work (i.e. do I need to check case sensitivity (`"<A"`) and spacing (ex: `"< a"`)?

Comment: Is your first snippet not working? It's much better to use it rather than parsing HTML yourself in the second snippet.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself ~ https://jsperf.com/

Comment: *"Is the second function even guaranteed to work?"* - It's guaranteed to *not* work, because it doesn't distinguish between `<a>`, `<article>`, `<audio>`, etc. elements.

Answer (score 0):

**This function works faster**

```js
function nodeContainsTag(node) {
    return node.tagName == "A" || node.getElementsByTagName("a").length > 0 ;
}
```

*Also querySelector works slower than these.*